# SwiftUI, List Row Add Button

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

In edit mode when you add ".onDelete" for the row a red circle with minus symbol appear like the this photo

[image]

I want to show a green circle with plus symbol (like the photo below) in edit mode, and when the user tap this green circle the row will be added to another section.

[image]

My issue is how to add this "green circle with plus symbol" shape to the row in edit mode.

Comment: I would try an `HStack` with the green button (possible an SFSymbol) and the text.

Comment: I looking for some default way like ".onDelete"

Comment: There is no *default way* for that, code your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a workaround but you can make the add row with the following code.

```
HStack {
            ZStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.leading, 0)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .padding(.leading, 0)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
            }
                        
            Text("add item")
                .padding(.leading, 8.0)
    } .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
        addItem() // your add item code
    })
    .frame(height: 32.0)
```